# Solid of revolution — shell method

Tags: graphics3d, rotation

I'm trying to plot the solid of revolution obtained by rotating the region enclosed by $y=x^{1/2}$ and $y=0$, with $x$ going from $0$ to $4$, about the line $x=5$.

```
{y==x^(1/2), y==0}
```

I cannot find any examples of it, only rotations about the line $x=0$.

Comment: Perhaps `https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RevolutionAxis.html` will help

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a homework problem, with no effort shown, thus outside the scope of the forum.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this is what you look for. Since the rotation axis does not contain the origin, we have to translate everything a little. Admittedly a bi inconvenient.

```
RevolutionPlot3D[
 {{t, 0}, {t, Sqrt[t + 5]}, {4 - 5, (t + 5)/2}},
 {t, -5, 4 - 5},
 PlotPoints -> 50
 ]
```

[image]